# Is the Android Support Library required when using Google Mobile Ads?

Tags: android-studio, google-play-services, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using Android Studio and when I try to "Sync Project with Gradle Files" or "Clean Project" it fails. I see the message:

```
Gradle 'MyTestProject' project refresh failed:
    Artifact 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0:support-v4.jar' not found.
```

I see in my MainActivity that *import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;* is having a problem, saying, "Cannot resolve symbol 'android'."

I don't even know if these two are related. In the past, I have been able to add support-v4 to the dependencies, and everything was fixed. However, I am trying that again right now, and I get the same project refresh failed message.

Oh yeah... my minSdkVersion is 14, and my targetSdkVersion is 19.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
Ok, I forgot to mention that I am including the Google Play Services as a dependency, but that doesn't help. For testing, I went ahead and created a new, bare-bones, project and gradle syncs fine if I don't touch it. However, as soon as I add the Google Play Services dependency to the gradle file, I get the same fail message noted above. Here is my gradle file and that fail message once again:

```
    apply plugin: 'android'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 19
        buildToolsVersion '19.0.3'

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 19
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                runProguard false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.+'
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    }
```

Message:

```
Gradle 'SimpleExample' project refresh failed:
Artifact 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.1:support-v4.jar' not found.
```

I'm thinking that something else must be going on?

Comment: That artifact name is messed up. I think there's an error in your build.gradle file; can you please add it to your question?

Comment: @ScottBarta I added the gradle file to my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Google Play Services dependency:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.4.52'
```

Comment: The Google Play Services dependency was already added. I edited my question and included my gradle file.